# How to configure DD_DOGSTATSD_MAPPER_PROFILES in datadog airflow integration?

Tags: airflow, datadog

I installed datadog-agent using helm upgrade/install and provided the `-f datadog.yaml` parameter. The datadog.yaml contains this entry:

```
...
agents:
  enabled: true
  useConfigMap: true
  customAgentConfig:
    # Autodiscovery for Kubernetes

    listeners:
       - name: kubelet
    config_providers:
      - name: kubelet
        polling: true
      - name: docker
        polling: true

    apm_config:
      enabled: false
      apm_non_local_traffic: true

    dogstatsd_mapper_profiles:
      - name: airflow
        prefix: "airflow."
        mappings:
          - match: "airflow.*_start"
            name: "airflow.job.start"
            tags:
              job_name: "$1"
          - match: "airflow.*_end"
            name: "airflow.job.end"
            tags:
              job_name: "$1"
          - match: "airflow.operator_failures_*"
...
```

But I don't see `DD_DOGSTATSD_MAPPER_PROFILES` env variable in the datadog-agent pod.
How can I inject this env variable to the datadog-agents?

Update 2/24/2022: I do see it's been added as a `ConfigMap` but it does not look like it is being mounted to the datadog-agent pod.

Update 3/4/2022: This yaml is working and I see the metrics in datadog dashboard. I do see it got mounted on the datadog-agent pod as config-map.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your datadog's helm chart:

```
datadog.env:
- name: DD_DOGSTATSD_MAPPER_PROFILES
  value: >
    [{"prefix":"airflow.","name":"airflow","mappings":[{"name":"airflow.job.start","match":"airflow.*_start","tags":{"job_name":"$1"}},{"name":"airflow.job.end","match":"airflow.*_end","tags":{"job_name":"$1"}},{"name":"airflow.job.heartbeat.failure","match":"airflow.*_heartbeat_failure","tags":{"job_name":"$1"}},{"name":"airflow.operator_failures","match":"airflow.operator_failures_*","tags":{"operator_name":"$1"}},{"name":"airflow.operator_successes","match":"airflow.operator_successes_*","tags":{"operator_name":"$1"}},{"match_type":"regex","name":"airflow.dag_processing.last_runtime","match":"airflow\\.dag_processing\\.last_runtime\\.(.*)","tags":{"dag_file":"$1"}},{"match_type":"regex","name":"airflow.dag_processing.last_run.seconds_ago","match":"airflow\\.dag_processing\\.last_run\\.seconds_ago\\.(.*)","tags":{"dag_file":"$1"}},{"match_type":"regex","name":"airflow.dag.loading_duration","match":"airflow\\.dag\\.loading-duration\\.(.*)","tags":{"dag_file":"$1"}},{"name":"airflow.dagrun.first_task_scheduling_delay","match":"airflow.dagrun.*.first_task_scheduling_delay","tags":{"dag_id":"$1"}},{"name":"airflow.pool.open_slots","match":"airflow.pool.open_slots.*","tags":{"pool_name":"$1"}},{"name":"airflow.pool.queued_slots","match":"pool.queued_slots.*","tags":{"pool_name":"$1"}},{"name":"airflow.pool.running_slots","match":"pool.running_slots.*","tags":{"pool_name":"$1"}},{"name":"airflow.pool.used_slots","match":"airflow.pool.used_slots.*","tags":{"pool_name":"$1"}},{"name":"airflow.pool.starving_tasks","match":"airflow.pool.starving_tasks.*","tags":{"pool_name":"$1"}},{"match_type":"regex","name":"airflow.dagrun.dependency_check","match":"airflow\\.dagrun\\.dependency-check\\.(.*)","tags":{"dag_id":"$1"}},{"match_type":"regex","name":"airflow.dag.task.duration","match":"airflow\\.dag\\.(.*)\\.([^.]*)\\.duration","tags":{"dag_id":"$1","task_id":"$2"}},{"match_type":"regex","name":"airflow.dag_processing.last_duration","match":"airflow\\.dag_processing\\.last_duration\\.(.*)","tags":{"dag_file":"$1"}},{"match_type":"regex","name":"airflow.dagrun.duration.success","match":"airflow\\.dagrun\\.duration\\.success\\.(.*)","tags":{"dag_id":"$1"}},{"match_type":"regex","name":"airflow.dagrun.duration.failed","match":"airflow\\.dagrun\\.duration\\.failed\\.(.*)","tags":{"dag_id":"$1"}},{"match_type":"regex","name":"airflow.dagrun.schedule_delay","match":"airflow\\.dagrun\\.schedule_delay\\.(.*)","tags":{"dag_id":"$1"}},{"name":"airflow.scheduler.tasks.running","match":"scheduler.tasks.running"},{"name":"airflow.scheduler.tasks.starving","match":"scheduler.tasks.starving"},{"name":"airflow.sla_email_notification_failure","match":"sla_email_notification_failure"},{"match_type":"regex","name":"airflow.dag.task_removed","match":"airflow\\.task_removed_from_dag\\.(.*)","tags":{"dag_id":"$1"}},{"match_type":"regex","name":"airflow.dag.task_restored","match":"airflow\\.task_restored_to_dag\\.(.*)","tags":{"dag_id":"$1"}},{"name":"airflow.task.instance_created","match":"airflow.task_instance_created-*","tags":{"task_class":"$1"}},{"name":"airflow.ti.start","match":"ti.start.*.*","tags":{"dagid":"$1","taskid":"$2"}},{"name":"airflow.ti.finish","match":"ti.finish.*.*.*","tags":{"dagid":"$1","state":"$3","taskid":"$2"}}]}]
```